# regex filter out words wrapped in certain characters

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to use regex in c# to handle a scenario where I want to find all instances of a word that are not wrapped in certain characters.  A quick example is below when trying to highlight the word "high"

```
highlight
[+highlight
highlight+]
[+highlight some more+]
[+highlight+]
```

I was trying to use negative look ahead and behind but this doesn't appear to play all that nice.  Something like this

```
(?<!\[[\+|-])\w*high\w*(?![\+|-]\])
```

The outcome I am after is the word "high" would be found in all but the last scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this pattern:

```
(?<=^|\s)(?<!\[[+|-])\w*high\w*|\w*high\w*(?![+|-]\])(?=$|\s)
```

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/df8lvQ/1)